# Use gdb to attach to process stuck in deadlock

Tags: c++, c, gdb

A program I've been trying to debug has shown the following behaviour

1. SEGFAULT happens in one of the threads
2. Custom signal handler implemented in the program called for SEGFAULT
3. The cleanup/deinit code as part of the signal handler gets called
4. Process reaches a deadlock state, presumably because a lock or some other resource that

Because of this coredump for the process is never generated, at the other threads keep running in a kind of infinite loop, due to this deadlock.

I tried to `gdb <binary_name> <pid>`, but the gdb prompt was just stuck, and did not proceed to attach to the process.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: If a segfault happens, you process is in a bad state and is generally unrecoverable. Probably best to let the program crash and debug the coredump

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 bugs, one which creates the SEGFAULT, and one in your signal handler. Which one do you want to fix (first)?

Comment: Thanks @doron, that's good advice. Using a legacy codebase that uses the sighandler to print a backtrace presumably in cases where the core cannot be dumped in a remote machine. 

Since I'm running this locally, I think I'll just go ahead and remove the sighandler. 

Since I'm running